# I can't access Specials Menu

Tags: modeling

I looked up online how to open the specials menu and it says to press <kbd>W</kbd> in edit mode. But my selection options are on <kbd>W</kbd> though. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

Menus are a bit different in version 2.80. You can access a contextual menu with right clicking with the default keymap now, but it is slightly different now then specials menu used to be, for example there is no Symmetrize in it, that is only in the Mesh menu now that does not have a shortcut by default.

You can use the *Quick Favourites Menu* to add and quickly access the functions you use most. You can access it by pressing <kbd>Q</kbd> and to add functions to it, right click on any function in any context menu and select *Add to Quick Favourites*.